# Typescript Generic : How to set type from Generic Object Properties

Tags: typescript

I have Container class that will receive dynamic object via constructor.
This dynamic object contains many different class.
I need to put one/some of that class to Container property without loosing type safe.

Here is what i try so far.
the error is `Property 'bbb1' does not exist on type 'A | B'.`
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1pnQRmgXmgInTAzxTXQCYd9DySBfJJUSGAIUVICNutc9vOxLt0p8BtJAybgo0AMIB7AHYAXMAEslAUwBOAHgAqAPg6owIEAC5oBgNyk1OgOZaV1gwG0A1loCeCgDMbAF17VGBlCBUdAFdgFQUdAAodLQgFGJ1gNPcASlNUaBUAC3UIADpzECpU9MzsiDDCkrLyxxcVGrSMrLSPfjw0GB9-IINQ0gYpCKUo6AVOACsqBDRrbQB3OCTcgBpoTnWtLdYd6Dp7GbmZtU1dKk35ZVvtZIXF3MvIhRAtcpAFE4kjcNK82mBnK5ygIMLkgA)

```
class A {
  aaa1 = "aaa1"
  aaa2 = "aaa2"
}

class B {
  bbb1 = "bbb1"
  bbb2 = "bbb2"
}

class Container<T> {
  all: T;
  target: T[keyof T];
  constructor(resources: T) {
    this.all = resources;
    this.target = resources["b" as keyof T];
  }
}

const obj = { a: new A(), b: new B() };
const container = new Container(obj);
console.log(container.target.bbb1) // Error
```

How to do this?
Thanks

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to know that `target` a `B` and not an `A`?  How in the constructor do you assume that `b` is even a valid key of `T`? If you don't want to lose type safety and you want to access the property then you need to communicate somewhere what the property is going to actually be.  Where does `b` come from, if the object is dynamic?  If you pass it into the constructor like in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WozE9m) then there's no problem. Does that satisfy your needs? If so I could write an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @jcalz. Thanks but  I need to set the key(any key) inside class container. not from outside like in your link. yes the resources object is dynamic.

Comment: I asked quite a few questions you haven't answered, so let me rephrase: You seem to be asking for two conflicting things: one is that the class itself manages the key and that information is hidden from the outside (since you write `"b" as keyof T`), and the other is that from outside it is apparently known that `container.target` has a `bbb1` property, and hence that the key is `"b"` (since you are unhappy about the error).  You can't really have it both ways. What is your actual goal? Please re-read the previous comment, and [edit] the question with more clarity and a proper [mre].

Comment: Right now it knows that `target` is either `A` or `B` but it has no idea which one. You hid that knowledge from the outside because of the way you wrote the class.  But I'm repeating myself.  At this point I have nothing left to offer unless you go back, re-read the comments, and do what they ask.  If that happens I'll check in again, otherwise I'll disengage. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz thanks. yes that information is hidden from outside. Only class Container will able to know what to do with that dynamic object and the keys. Outside class Container just need to access from class Container without knowing the actual object that sent to Container constructor. I begin to think what I want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
  aaa1 = "aaa1";
  aaa2 = "aaa2";
}

class B {
  bbb1 = "bbb1";
  bbb2 = "bbb2";
}

class Container<T, K extends keyof T> {
  all: T;
  key: K;
  target: T[K];
  constructor(resources: T, key: K) {
    this.all = resources;
    this.key = key;
    this.target = resources[key];
  }
}

const obj = { a: new A(), b: new B() };
const container = new Container(obj, "b");
console.log(container.target.bbb1); // No error
console.log(container.Key); // "b"
```

introduce a generic constraint `K` that represents the key of the resources object.

Comment: thanks but I need to set the key inside class container.  your code put the key from outside. can you help? thanks

Comment: @DonJohn I have modifed the code 
We introduce a generic constraint `K` for the `key`.
We add a `key` property to store the key within the `Container class.`

Comment: I cannot set the key outside class Container like this  `new Container(obj, "b");` Only inside class Container that know what to do with the keys and the object.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution. I have changed it a bit without changing the type-safety. Now it's not throwing that error.

```
class A {
  aaa1 = "aaa1"
  aaa2 = "aaa2"
}

class B {
  bbb1 = "bbb1"
  bbb2 = "bbb2"
}

class Container<T> {
  all: T;
  target: T[keyof T];
  constructor(resources: T) {
    this.all = resources;
    this.target = resources["b" as keyof T] ? resources["b" as keyof T] : resources["a" as keyof T];
  }
}

const obj = { a: new A(), b: new B() };
const container = new Container(obj);

if (container.target instanceof B) {
  console.log(container.target.bbb1)
} else if (container.target instanceof A) {
  console.log(container.target.aaa1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but seems to get `target`. I need to check if that instance of something. or cast it to something. I was expecting the compiler will able to know without the need of additional check like in your example `if (container.target instanceof B) {
  console.log(container.target.bbb1)}`. I begin to think that what I want is not possible

Comment: instance of: it's not casting to anything. but check the target's instance type. A or B.